# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't start async operation

Tags: java, android

I use these code for payment and check proof of purchase on server:

http://www.aghsatiha.com/pardakht.txt

but it is not working, and I have this error:

```
05-21 23:04:06.277: E/AndroidRuntime(4204): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't start async operation (launchPurchaseFlow) because another async operation(refresh inventory) is in progress.
05-21 23:04:06.277: E/AndroidRuntime(4204):     at com.util.IabHelper.flagStartAsync(IabHelper.java:8  22)
05-21 23:04:06.277: E/AndroidRuntime(4204):     at com.util.IabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(IabHelper.ja  va:373)
05-21 23:04:06.277: E/AndroidRuntime(4204):     at com.util.IabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(IabHelper.ja  va:338)
05-21 23:04:06.277: E/AndroidRuntime(4204):     at com.deser.srp.Kharid$4.onClick(Kharid.java:77)
05-21 23:04:06.277: E/AndroidRuntime(4204):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
05-21 23:04:06.277: E/AndroidRuntime(4204):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770  )
05-21 23:04:06.277: E/AndroidRuntime(4204):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808  )
05-21 23:04:06.277: E/AndroidRuntime(4204):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:10  3)
05-21 23:04:06.277: E/AndroidRuntime(4204):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
05-21 23:04:06.277: E/AndroidRuntime(4204):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.jav  a:5333)
05-21 23:04:06.277: E/AndroidRuntime(4204):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 23:04:06.277: E/AndroidRuntime(4204):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-21 23:04:06.277: E/AndroidRuntime(4204):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCa  ller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
05-21 23:04:06.277: E/AndroidRuntime(4204):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit  .java:645)
05-21 23:04:06.277: E/AndroidRuntime(4204):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone help me?